# Verification of a sequence with exactly two limit points.

Tags: real-analysis

I was not allowed to edit the previous question because people spent their time and energy constructing an answer, therefore I have asked it again, with my initial error in formulating my answers corrected.

---

Is it true that this example I came up with, namely the sequence $$a_n=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$$
Has exactly $4$ limit points/accumulation points? What I tried to do was symmetrically pick an infinite amount of points that lie on the unit circle and all hop between four exact points $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ and $\pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3}$.

Is equality fine for accumulation points is basically what I am  asking.

I  also was thinking of an example with infinitely many accumulation points and wondered if the same example would cut it:

$$b_n = n \cos(n) $$
Since it oscillates back and forth it comes back to every single point eventually.

---

As an alternative way of getting four  accumulation points I could define unions of the sets $s_a= \{ a+ \frac{1}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ for values $a=0, 1,2,3$ but this example feels very contrived and I do not know how to formulate this in terms of a sequence other than just listing the elements one by one in set notation: $\{ \frac{1}{1}, 1+\frac{1}{1},  2+\frac{1}{1} \dots, 1+ \frac{1}{n}, 2+ \frac{1}{n} \dots  \}$

Comment: You have asked a question with the same title less than one hour ago, moreover without mentionning it. This is not a good practice. You should have modified the text of the initial question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- $n=1 \implies a_1=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi }{2}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt 3}2$
- $n=2 \implies a_2=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \pi\right)=-\frac12$
- $n=3 \implies a_3=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{3\pi }{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$
- $n=4 \implies a_4=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi\right)=\frac12$
- $n=5 \implies a_5=a_1$

For the second question, yes of curse $b_n$ oscillates diverging assuming values $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\cos n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. From that to conlcude that $n\cos n$ is dense on the real line is not so trivial, see the related

- [Is $n \sin n$ dense on the real line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221018/505767)
- [Does this sequence $a(n) = \frac{1}{n^3\sin(n)}$ converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998694/505767)
- [Is it true that $\varliminf_{n \rightarrow +\infty} |n \sin n| = 0$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/144080)
- [Convergence of $\sum(n^3\sin^2n)^{-1}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24579)

Comment: Could I simply take $\cos(n)$ and that would give me an infinite amount of points because of density?

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yes, refer to the following [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843664/505767)

Comment: I mean one sort of needs to prove that you will never start repeating a finite set of points.

Comment: ah, very nice, thank you.